# Insertion method in circular doubly linked list in java

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am a **beginner in java**. I am trying to write a program that inserts a node at a given position and displays the entire linked list. However, my nodes seem to be not getting inserted and when I display the linked list only the first node value is getting displayed. Could someone please explain where I am going wrong?

//Here,location is index location. Index starts from 0 and ends with size-1 just like an array.

//Code for insertion

```
public void insertIntoCircularDoublyLinkedList(int location,int num){
    Node node=new Node();
      Node tempNode=head;
      int index=0;

      while(index<location){
        tempNode=tempNode.next;
        index++;
      }
      node.prev=tempNode.prev;
      node.next=tempNode;
      tempNode.prev.next=node;
      tempNode.prev=node;
    }
    size++;
  }
```

//Code for traversal

```
 void traverseCDLL() {
    if (head != null) {
      Node tempNode = head;
      for (int i=0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print(tempNode.value);
        if (i != size - 1) {
          System.out.print(" -> ");
        }
        tempNode = tempNode.next;
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("The CDLL does not exist.");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
```

//Main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
CircularDoublyLinkedList CDLL=new CircularDoublyLinkedList();   
CDLL.createCircularDoublyLinkedList(8);   
CDLL.insertIntoCircularDoublyLinkedList(1, 1);
CDLL.insertIntoCircularDoublyLinkedList(2, 2);
CDLL.insertIntoCircularDoublyLinkedList(3, 3);
CDLL.insertIntoCircularDoublyLinkedList(4, 4);

CDLL.traverseCDLL();
}
```

Output:

```
8 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign a value to your node. If you designed the `Node` class well, its constructor can take this value as argument.

Some other issues:

- When the given location is 0, the new node should become the head of the list, otherwise your new node will be seen as the *last* node in the list.
- When the list is empty, you should avoid errors and just create the head node that references itself and return
- I would not use the term "CircularLinkedList" in the method name, as your class already bears that name, and it is clear what this method deals with.

So:

```
public void insert(int location, int num) {
    Node node = new Node(num); // <-- pass num to the constructor
    if (head == null) { // Boundary case
        head = node;
        head.next = head.prev = head;
        return;
    }
    Node tempNode = head;
    int index = 0;
    while (index < location) {
        tempNode = tempNode.next;
        index++;
    }
    node.prev = tempNode.prev;
    node.next = tempNode;
    tempNode.prev.next = node;
    tempNode.prev = node;
    if (location == 0) { // Make new node the head
        head = node;
    }
    size++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to set `node.value = num` in `insertIntoCircularDoublyLinkedList`.